# Problema al registrar datos en una lista JAVA JFrame Form

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo una lista en un Jframe Form la cual le añado datos, y quisiera saber por qué no me agrega realice las conversiones correspondiente, y me aseguro siempre de **no** ingresar datos erróneos. Estoy tratando de agregar esos datos, de la imagen que viene, a una lista.

Dejaré el código que llevo.

Mi frame se llama AgregarAnilloFrame

```
package FeriaPrincipal;

import FeriaServicio.ListaJoya;
import feriaartesanalapp.Anillo;

public class AgregarAnilloFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public AgregarAnilloFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    

    BtnAgregar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    BtnAgregar.setText("AGREGAR");
    BtnAgregar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BtnAgregarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });                      

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    
        this.TXT_Codigo.setText(" ");
        this.TXT_Diametro.setText(" ");
        this.TXT_Material.setText(" ");
        this.TXT_Nombre.setText(" ");
        this.TXT_Precio.setText(" ");
        this.TXT_Stock.setText(" ");
    
    }                                        

    private void BtnAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    
        Anillo a = Anillo();
        String vCodigo = this.TXT_Codigo.getText();
        int cod = Integer.parseInt(vCodigo); 
        a.setCodigo(cod);
   
        a.setNombre(this.TXT_Nombre.getText());
        a.setMaterial(this.TXT_Material.getText());
        String vDiametro = this.TXT_Diametro.getText();
        double diam = Double.parseDouble(vDiametro);
   
        a.setDiametro(diam);
   
        String vPrecio = this.TXT_Precio.getText();
        int precio = Integer.parseInt(vPrecio);
   
        a.setPrecio(precio);
   
        String vStock = this.TXT_Stock.getText();
        int stock = Integer.parseInt(vStock);
        a.setStock(stock);
   
        ListaJoya.add(a);
        
   
    } 

}
```

Para que no quedara tan largo no puse todo solo los eventos. En el del boton Agregar está el codigo que agrega a la lista.

Y este error obtengo, pondré una imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cual es el error ahí. No creo que sea el double para el diametro usar puntos o comas para separar el decimal, ya que probando ambas maneras el error sigue. Ya el resto no sé que puede ser.

Como dato extra añado la clase Anillo.

```
package feriaartesanalapp;

public class Anillo extends Joya{

    public double getDiametro() {
        return diametro;
    }

    public void setDiametro(double diametro) {
        this.diametro = diametro;
    }

    private double diametro;

    public Anillo(int codigo, String nombre, String material, int precio, int stock, double diametro) {
        super(codigo, nombre, material, precio, stock);
        this.diametro = diametro;
    }
}
```

Comment: no incluiste el código fuente de Anillo pero es el constructor de Anillo aparentemente el que está fallando.

No se qué haces ahí pero supongo que estás llamando algún método no soportado por una colección.

Comment: mmmm lo agregaré, y revisaré que sucede.

Comment: tu clase Anillo no tiene "default" constructor.. supongo que está heredando de Joya

Comment: Si hereda de Joya

Answer (score 0):

```
//ESTE JButton1ActionPerformed NO ENTIENDO QUE ES Y TAMPOCO ENTIENDO QUE HACE EL BOTON AGREGAR , TENES UNA BASE DE DATOS?

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    this.TXT_Codigo.setText(" ");
    this.TXT_Diametro.setText(" ");
    this.TXT_Material.setText(" ");
    this.TXT_Nombre.setText(" ");
    this.TXT_Precio.setText(" ");
    this.TXT_Stock.setText(" ");

}
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta o una pregunta?

Comment: Dije que el ""jbutton1ActionPerformed"" esta mal o eso parece ese 1 no pinta nada ahi, y lo demas del codigo no se entiende muy bien capaz si pega mas codigo se podria entender mejor

Comment: La pregunta te la hice por que este espacio es solo para respuestas, por favor lee [answer], cuando tengas 50 de rep. podrás comentar en cualquier lado

Comment: Tiene razon BetaM. Pero igual te responderé. Ahi no dice pero si te fijas bien, dentro de ese boton, es la funcion del boton LIMPIAR de la imagen. No puse más codigo porque iba a ser largo, agregué solo el codigo funcional. De mi clase AgregarAnillo. Ya que el main solo llama a ese JFrame.

Comment: Ademas dije que estaba agregando los datos a una lista, lo que se entiende que no estoy trabajando con bases de datos.